# Who knows the pixel size of the image(640*480) of kinect RGB camera

Tags: kinect, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know other cameras' parameters, which are often given. For example, CCD's is 80 pixel/mm. I've asked others, and maybe the pixel size should be calculated. If you've ever done this or knew something, hope to get your results or quotes.
Thx in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209418/who-knows-the-pixel-size-of-the-image(640*480)-of-kinect-rgb-camera/) by [gmir](https://answers.ros.org/users/22446/gmir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on the CCD the camera is mounting. Check for the datasheet of your camera for this information and, if it is not showed, you can try to get the model of the chip, and search it in google.

Optionally, if there's no information, you can simply calibrate your camera and use some trigonometry with a known object to get your pixel size.

[UPDATE]
According to [this website](http://www.chipworks.com/en/technical-competitive-analysis/resources/blog/teardown-of-the-microsoft-kinect-focused-on-motion-capture/), its pixel size is 2.8 um.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2015-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gmir](https://answers.ros.org/users/22446/gmir/) on 2015-05-18**:
Thx for your reply.
1, I'm gonna to check out the (Color CMOS) VNA38209015 chip.
2, Or my graduation project is due to be handed in...
Aw~_~

**Comment by [zhangying295](https://answers.ros.org/users/24913/zhangying295/) on 2015-10-26**:
Hello, have you found the answer. I cannot found the size of the CCD.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2015-10-27**:
6 x 4.5 mm according to [Khoshelham2012](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/12/2/1437)

**Comment by [zhangying295](https://answers.ros.org/users/24913/zhangying295/) on 2015-10-28**:
Thank you very much!

**Comment by [zhangying295](https://answers.ros.org/users/24913/zhangying295/) on 2015-11-03**:
the result is a little different from that in [link text](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/ftp/articles/pajdla/Smisek-CDC4CV-2011.pdf)

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2015-11-03**:
Who knows. Are there maybe two versions with different hardware?